# Define and return two dimensional string array from function in C

Tags: c, string, function, return, user-defined-functions

I want to use a two-dimensional string array ***(new_sentence)*** that I produced in the function named ***parse()*** in the main function (or any other function). The code I wrote is below.

***strtok()*** and ***strcpy()*** functions work fine. I can access all elements of the ***new_sentence*** array within the ***parse()*** function. However, I could not pass this array into the main function.

I can understand that there is a problem with the return value of the ***parse()*** function and the definition inside the main function.  I did some research on similar issues but couldn't figure it out. Can you help me.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char *parse(char *s);

int main () {
    
   char str[1000] = "This-is-test-sentence";
   
   char *n_sentence = parse(str);
   for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
   {
       printf("%s\n", n_sentence[j]);
   }
   return 0;
}

const char *parse(char *s)
{
   char *delim = "-";
   char *token;
   char new_sentence[4][15];

   token = strtok(s, delim);

   int numberOfWord = 0;
   while( token != NULL ) {

      strcpy(new_sentence[numberOfWord], token);
      token = strtok(NULL, delim);
      numberOfWord++;
   }
   
   return new_sentence;
}
```

Comment: Returning a function-local array is UB. Look up dynamic allocation.

Comment: One option is to return statically allocated buffer (declare `new_sentence` as `static`. It is non-reenterable and not thread-safe. Another option is to allocate buffer in heap. Buffer should be freed by caller then. Another one is to allocate buffer in caller and pass pointer to existing buffer to `parse()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to go about your problem, based on your code and my own snippets:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 1000

int parse(char *s, char *n_sentence[], int max_size);

int main () {

   char str[] = "This-is-test-sentence";
   char* n_sentence[MAX_WORDS];

   int tot_words = parse(str, n_sentence, MAX_WORDS);

   printf("Total number of words: %d\n", tot_words);
   for (int j = 0; j<tot_words; j++)
   {
       printf("%s\n", n_sentence[j]);
   }
   return 0;
}

int parse(char *s, char* new_sentence[], int max_size)
{
   char *delim = "-";
   int numberOfWord = 0;

   new_sentence[numberOfWord++]= strtok(s, delim);

   while(((numberOfWord < max_size) && (new_sentence[numberOfWord] = strtok(NULL, delim)) != NULL)) {
      ++numberOfWord;
   }

   return numberOfWord;
}
```

The code declares your array of parsed strings in the main and passes it to `parse` as an argument (to be filled with words). This avoids the undefined behavior caused by returning a local array created in `parse` (that ceases to exist after `parse` terminates).

`n_sentence` is now a proper array of strings - the code only specifies how many strings, at most, it can store. But the length of an individual string can be anything. `parse` returns the number of strings that were retrieved from parsing - it is a convenient approach that makes it easier to work with that array as you can see from the printing part.

Lastly, `parse` itself got rearranged - I used my old approach for parsing lines instead of your `strcpy` one. I recommend you study this code in detail with a book/documentation. Also, never ignore compiler warnings and ideally, set them to the highest possible level.

EDIT: following a suggestion by @JonathanLeffler `parse` now checks the maximum allowable size of the input string array and stops parsing - adding strings if that size is reached. This way the code avoids potential writing past that array boundaries. In this case, maximum size is 1000 words. I made a separate argument to `parse` instead of using the macro `MAX_WORDS` to make it, as a function, more autonomous. The `while()` works correctly because of [short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: You should pass the size of the output array to the parsing function so that it does not write out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I answered this question to practice my C and used some old code of mine, old code full of bad practices. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your `parse()` function is the classic case of a string-split function. If you allocate the result on the heap then you can handle an arbitrary number of results. I personally would not use `strtok` here: it adds a bit of complexity that isn't needed, it modifies the input, and it isn't re-entrant (you can't use it in multiple threads, check out `strtok_r`).

```c
char **split(const char *s, char delim, size_t *count)
{
        *count = 0;
        const char *p = s;
        char **result = NULL;
        for (; *p != '\0'; ++p) {
                if (*p != delim)
                        continue;

                char **new_result = realloc(result, (*count + 1) * sizeof(char *));
                if (new_result == NULL)
                        goto error;

                result = new_result;
                result[*count] = calloc(p - s + 1, sizeof(char));
                if (result[*count] == NULL)
                        goto error;

                strncpy(result[*count], s, p - s);
                ++*count;
                s = p + 1;
        }

        char **new_result = realloc(result, (*count + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        if (new_result == NULL)
                goto error;

        result = new_result;
        result[*count] = calloc(p - s + 1, sizeof(char));
        if (result[*count] == NULL)
                goto error;

        strncpy(result[*count], s, p - s);
        ++*count;
        return result;

error:
        for (size_t i = 0; i < *count; ++i)
                free(result[i]);

        free(result);
        *count = 0;
        return NULL;
}
```

Here is a test driver for the split function:

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
                size_t count = 0;
                char **result = split(argv[i], '-', &count);
                printf("'%s'\n", argv[i]);
                for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                        printf("\t'%s'\n", result[i]);

                for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                        free(result[i]);

                free(result);
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Some tests covering a few edge cases:

```bash
$ ./split -string-one string-two- string--three string-four
'-string-one'
        ''
        'string'
        'one'
'string-two-'
        'string'
        'two'
        ''
'string--three'
        'string'
        ''
        'three'
'string-four'
        'string'
        'four'
```

If this is a homework assignment I highly recommend studying the code and trying to recreate it from scratch.